# How to change the shape of the bars in barplot using coreplot in iOS

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios6.1

As I want to customize the shape(Sharp edges at the tip of the bar) of the bars in the barChart. I am searching for the property to change the bar style and I didn't found any.

Suggest me with any ideas how to do this.

I am also uploading the image what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create a shape for bar plots like this, with the current implementation. The only way, I can imagine, to achieve something like that is to use annotations that contain images of the tips and must be placed so that they look as if they naturally belong to a bar. But that's quite expensive.